# Title too long in Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I have a long title for my presentation that goes out of the frame. If I try to separate it with '\' then the second line has a different format as the first line. I think I should change settings but I don't know how.

This is the template I'm using:
https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-presentation-template/pphckrjbyyzy

Comment: It seems a by design  behavior of the flux theme to make the line break a kind of fake subtitle, but  you can override this design with some  `\title{\color{black}TITLE \\\Huge\bfseries\color{black} MORE TITLE}`

Comment: You could try putting tht title into a \parbox{\linewidth}{...}.

Answer (score 2):

The theme does not consider the possibility of a multiline title, it misses the `text width` option for the node with the title:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

% Define where theme files are located. ('/styles')
\usepackage{styles/fluxmacros}
\usefolder{styles}
% Use Flux theme v0.1 beta
% Available style: asphalt, blue, red, green, gray 
\usetheme[style=asphalt]{flux}

\title{a very long title spanning over multiple lines and more lines}
\subtitle{WITH CUSTOM BACKGROUND AND LOGO}
\author{GKG}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \hspace*{-1pt}\node[anchor=west,sider] at (current page.west){};
            \node[anchor=south west,sider, fill=primary, minimum height=0.3\paperheight] at (current page.south west){};
            \node[align=center,text width=\textwidth] at (current page.center){
                \usebeamerfont{title}\color{primary}\inserttitle\\[0.3cm]
                \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\color{Gray!90!black}\insertsubtitle\\[0.1cm]
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{footer}\rule{0.7\paperwidth}{0.2pt} \\[0.35cm]
                \usebeamerfont{author}\color{Gray}\insertauthor\\[0.3cm]
             \usebeamerfont{institute}\color{Gray}\insertinstitute
            };
            %\node[anchor=south,outer ysep=0.4cm] at (current page.south){\small\color{Gray!90}\insertdate};
            %\node[anchor=south east,icon] at (current page.south east)(logo){\includegraphics[width=\logo@width, height=\logo@height, keepaspectratio]{\inserttitlegraphic}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\titlepage

\end{document}
```

[image]